# jQuery scroll left is not working when using position absolute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My HTML like this

```
<body>
  <div id="next" style="postion:fixed;">Next<br><br></div>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="cont">
     <div class="Element" style="background:blue; left:0; "></div>
     <div class="Element" style="background:orange; left:100%;"></div>
     <div class="Element" style="background:pink; left:200%;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My js for scroll-left

```
$('#next').click(function() {   
    $('#container').animate({
        scrollLeft: $('#container').scrollLeft() + 400
    });
});
```

css

```
#container{
overflow-x:hidden; 
overflow-y:hidden;
}
.Element{
width:100%; 
height:50%;
position:absolute;
height:50%;
}
```

I tried to display the div tag with `position:absolute` with `scrollLeft` function. But scrollleft is not working on `position:absolute`.  But `position:relative` is works fine. I want to display the div tag with position absolute with scrolling option? How can i do it?

JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/aja_aja/s9snvk5s/9/

Comment: can you provide a fiddle.??

Comment: You have a typo in 'style="postion:fixed;"' at first line

Comment: @TienNguyen This is just for display `Next` div tag. It is not a problem

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle with your html included

Comment: @AndrewLyndem I edited my question. I want to scroll the `container` in left with position absolute. I dont know how to use the fiddle. I tried, but not get.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `#container` element needs to have the [`overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) property set something like `overflow: auto` in order to make the element scrollable. By default, the `overflow` is `visible` which mean the element does not scroll. You will also need to add positioning to the `#container`, and set the `width` and `height`.

### Working Example ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hpns0eor/)):

```js
$('#next').click(function() { 
    $('#container').animate({
        scrollLeft: $('#container').scrollLeft() + 400
    });
});
```

```css
.Element {
    padding:0px;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
}

#container {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="next" style="postion:fixed;">Next
    <br>
    <br>
</div>
<div id="container">
    <div id="cont">
        <div class="Element" style="background:blue; left:0;">aaa</div>
        <div class="Element" style="background:orange; left:100%;">bbb</div>
        <div class="Element" style="background:yellow; left:200%;">ccc</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to scroll left.

```
 $('#next').click(function() {  
        $('html, body').animate({
                  scrollLeft: 500
    }, 800);
    });
```

Where 500 is the margin and 800 is speed.

Edit:

And if you want to move container to the left. Use the following code.

```
 $('#next').click(function() {  

        $("#container").animate({
    'marginLeft': '-=450px'
}, 500);
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for ur rply. I want to scroll the `container` tag only. How can i do it.?

Comment: For the container bag only, you will need to put the margin in minus within animate tag. I have edited the answer. see above please. Thanks

Comment: @ user2505019 Your edited answer is not working. Can you provide JSfiddle

Comment: @ user2505019 Else any other option instead of `position:absolute`? only the `position:absolute` make the problem to scrolling.

Comment: You have 3 bags inside cont and container. Do you know how much width they will have? Its possible without position:absolute but please elaborate your problem clearly.

Comment: Each `Element` tag have `100%` width. I want to align the all 'element` tag in left side. But i not expect the `float:left`. without `float` it is possible?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But your answer is not fit for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73892/discussion-between-aja-and-user2505019).